# Struggling with output of grep into an array

Tags: linux, grep, array

Please note I'm not a developer but I have requirements where I'm trying to search an SVN repository for files containing certain table names.  I have built this script on the basis of many things I have read here.

```
printf "table_name, file_name, full_path\n" >> export_list.txt
while read table
do
extract=($(egrep -ilrs $table /path/to/file | egrep -i tag | egrep -v backup))
file_name=$(basename $extract)
printf "$table, $file_name, $extract\n" >> export_list.txt
done < table_list.txt
```

I am expecting output like this

```
table_name, file_name, full_path
SOMETABLENAME, SomeFileName, /path/to/file/tag1.0/SomeFileName
SOMETABLENAME, SomeFileName, /path/to/file/tag2.0/SomeFileName
SOMETABLENAME, SomeFileName1, /path/to/file/tag1.0/SomeFileName1
SOMETABLENAME, SomeFileName1, /path/to/file/tag2.0/SomeFileName1
```

Instead I am only getting one line back for SOMETABLENAME, the first one it finds.

The use of the array came from 
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890764/store-grep-output-in-an-array).  I have also read the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890764/store-grep-output-in-an-array) but to be honest I don't really understand it.

If there are other problems with my script (wrong grep etc), or some other better way of doing it, I'd appreciate the help.

EDIT:

table_list.txt is 2000 lines that looks like this

```
BI_CLAIMS_SUMMARY
BI_CLAIMS_SUMMARY_AUDIT
BI_MEDS_AUDIT
BI_MEDS_PATIENTS
BI_MEDS_SUMMARY
```

EDIT:

I have made the changes as suggested by Jessie below (thank you), but the output looks very much the same as before I tried to use my (wrong) version of the array.

```
table_name, file_name, full_path
BI_CLAIMS_SUMMARY, nohup.out, /sas/data/prod/EIP/depot/hiu/data_extract/tags/1.2/source/pl_sql/bi_claims_sum_plan_proc.sql
/sas/data/prod/EIP/depot/hiu/data_extract/tags/1.2/source/pl_sql/bi_claims_sum_proc.sql
/sas/data/prod/EIP/depot/hiu/sql_refresh/tags/1.0/source/10_load_claims_summary_audit_sqlserver.sas
/sas/data/prod/EIP/depot/hiu/sql_refresh/tags/1.0/resources/automation/nohup.out
BI_CLAIMS_SUMMARY_AUDIT, 10_load_claims_summary_audit_sqlserver.sas, /sas/data/prod/EIP/depot/hiu/data_extract/tags/1.2/source/pl_sql/bi_sum_claims_audit_proc.sql
/sas/data/prod/EIP/depot/hiu/data_extract/tags/1.3/source/pl_sql/bi_sum_claims_audit_proc.sql
/sas/data/prod/EIP/depot/hiu/data_extract/tags/1.4/source/pl_sql/bi_sum_claims_audit_proc.sql
/sas/data/prod/EIP/depot/hiu/meds/tags/1.0/source/HIU_RISK_REFRESH_CLAIMS_SUMMARY_AUDIT.sas
/sas/data/prod/EIP/depot/hiu/sql_refresh/tags/1.0/source/10_load_claims_summary_audit_sqlserver.sas
```

I'm expecting the BI_CLAIMS_SUMMARY to appear on each line.  And also the filename nohup.out appears under the file_name, so it is not splitting the output of the grep correctly

Answer (score 1):

First let me say sorry because I'm not exactly sure what your issue is at this time but I believe it is related to the way you are calling the array, and I have the following suggestions:

```
n=0
printf '%s,%s,%s\n' 'table_name' 'file_name' 'full_path' >> export_list.txt
while read -r table
do
    extract[$n]=$(egrep -ilrs "$table" /path/to/file | egrep -i tag | egrep -v backup)
    file_name=$(basename "${extract[$n]}")
    printf '%s,%s,%s\n' "$table" "$file_name" "${extract[$n]}" >> export_list.txt
    n=$((n+1))
done < table_list.txt
```

1. The `printf` format string should always be separate from the actual content.  (`printf '%s,%s,%s\n' 'table_name' 'file_name' 'full_path'`)
2. When using `read` you should almost always use the `-r` argument.  This will allow it to read the `\` escape character as a literal
3. **always** double quote your variables.  Because of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/237982) and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/237982).
4. There is a special syntax that must be used when referring to an array/array element.  That is `${array[@]}` (entire array) or `${array[0]}` (first element in the array).  When you call it as `$array` you will always get only the first element.
5. Because of the above we need a way to ensure we are grabbing the correct array element on each iteration.  For this I have added the `n` variable which will be incremented on each iteration of your loop.

note: There doesn't appear to be any need to use an array at all in this.  Unless your code goes on to use `extract` in other places you could simply set it as a variable and reset it on each iteration of the loop.

Also note:  Your question is tagged with "shell-script" but arrays are not specified by the POSIX standard so while most /bin/sh versions support them, there is no guarantee that yours does.

Comment: Thank you jessie.  I've made the changes you suggested.  I have edited my post to show the output of the changes, but sadly it's still giving me the same result as before I introduced the array